# frequency of elements in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data frame (this is an example and the dataframe can contain more columns)

```
SelectVar 
     a    b    c    l    p    v   aa   ff
1 Dxa2 Dxa2 Dxa2 Dxa2 Dxa2 Dxb2 Dxb2 Dxb2
2 Dxb2 Dxb2 Dxb2 Dxd2 Dxi2 Dxc2 Dxd2 Dxi2
3 Dxc2 Dxd2 Dxi2 Dxi2 tneg Dxd2 Dxi2 tneg
```

I would like to count the frequency of the elements without convert it into a vector and using table or by indicating the element like in

```
length(SelectVar[SelectVar=="Dxa2"])
```

Is there any other way as to count the frequencies of the elements than the two mentioned in the above paragraph for the sample dataframe.

Comment: What's wrong with `table`?

Comment: What is your ultimate goal?  If you can explain what you're going to do with the frequency counts, we may be able to suggest a different approach.

Comment: I produce repeated dataframes as above where the column names can be different, longer or shorter all of three rows. I would not want to have to have to manipulate the data every time as I would like to link the three most frequent elements to another expression. in creating a vector to use by a table I have to manipulate the data every time due that both the elements and column names may be different

Comment: Isn't constructing a simple function helpful for what you describe in your comment? Something like `f = function(mydf) sort(table(unlist(mydf)))`. And, also, maybe you could, somehow, have all your dataframes in a list and manipulate them with `lapply`?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are using `data.frame` for this?  If the columns all contain the same data type, `matrix` seems more appropriate and perhaps easier to manipulate.

Comment: I think you are right a matrix is more appropriate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you asked the same question yesterday, [Counting the frequency of an element in a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21565605/counting-the-frequency-of-an-element-in-a-data-frame)

answer modified from, dickoa's answer to previous question
instead of `data.frame`, if you make it matrix, `table()` does not need vectorization and it should work.

```
df <- read.table(text = "   b    c    e    f    g    h    j 
1 Dxa2 Dxa2 Dxa2 Dxa2 Dxa2 Dxa2 Dxa2
2 Dxb2 Dxb2 Dxb2 Dxb2 Dxc2 Dxc2 Dxc2
3 Dxd2 Dxi2 tneg tpos Dxd2 Dxi2 tneg", header = TRUE, row.names = 1)

ll<-data.frame(table(as.matrix(df)))
```

now, you can sort by `freq` and select top 3

```
head(ll[order(ll$Freq, decreasing=T),],3)
```

Comment: I did not realize that by converting into matrix I could make the job much easier, thank you